# Styling a button using CSS and mutiple images from a spritesheet

Tags: html, css, button, styling

I have the following image in a sprite sheet and want to use it to style a button:

[image]

I have tried everything I can think of (even going as far as pseudo elements) but I can't get it to work. I had thought something like this should work:

```
.ui-button {
height:45px;
background-image: url(../button.png), url(../button.png), url(../media/button.png);
background-size: 8px 45px, 8px 45px, 3px 45px !important;
background-position: -63px -1px, -77px -1px, -73px -1px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat;
}
```

but it doesn't.  The background-size bits are the size of each chunk from the sprite sheet that I am using and the position is the top left coordinates of each part in the sprite sheet.  Clearly I am doing something wrong. What?

Edit:  here's the whole image:

[image]

Comment: Is this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/C9f33.png the image you are using? Or is it only a part of a larger image?

Comment: It's part of a larger image (different button styles, menu components, etc).

Comment: Is it possible to post the full image? I tried with only the small image and it works (with removing some parts) http://jsfiddle.net/men62/2/

Comment: added the whole image for you...

Comment: The button i need to apply the style to has a width of 60px, fyi

Comment: You could use :before and :after to add the caps

Comment: @twodayslate.  I tried that but I couldn't get it to work. Bit of a CSS n00b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have tried with JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kpusc/

```
.ui-button {
    height:45px;
    width:18px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipKrd.png);
    background-position: -72px -1px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    border:0;
}

.ui-button:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:45px;
    width:8px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipKrd.png);
    background-position: -64px -1px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;left:0;top:0;
}

 .ui-button:after {
     content:"";
     display:block;
     height:45px;
     width:8px;
     background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipKrd.png);
     background-position: -78px -1px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     position:absolute;right:0;top:0;
 }
```

​

Unfortunately I only could make it as wide as 34px. Since I can't make the center content to repeat itself.

I suppose you need to make the center part wider than at least 60px so that it could be applied as the `.ui-button` background-image (or perhaps make it as a separate file altogether, so it would be possible to repeat).

I'd like to know if there's another workaround though.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  At least you've got me a bit further along than where I was before.  Just curious if anybody else has any ideas on how to get the centre image repeating without having to use a separate image.  If no more replies by the end of the day, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: No more comments so you win the prize.  Thanks again for your help.  In the end I have created a much larger centre section image for the button than I should really need (80px), then I can chop out the required size, depending on the size of the button that needs styling.

Comment: No problem. Sorry for not bein able to offer more!